# Rails: 3rd party API call in the create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud, faker

Hello I am new to Ruby On Rails. Gone through a few basic crud applications up to this point and I'm now trying to spice it up.

I am doing a pretty basic application to save articles and leave notes on them. But instead of the typical, write your own article and then submit format, I am using a 3rd party random data generator to generate articles for me.

it comes up with some pretty entertaining Titles and some ipsum body
eg:
The Monkey's Raincoat.
Harum accusamus delectus animi.

I have used the 3rd party api to generate my seed data in db/seeds.rb

```
5.times do 
Article.create({
    title: Faker::Book.title,
    body: Faker::Lorem.sentence
})
end
```

Currently I am wanting to do something extremely similar in the create method of my Articles controller. Right now I have a button in my New view that I want to trigger the create method mentioned

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @articles = Article.order('created_at DESC');
    # render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message:'Loaded articles', data:@articles},status: :ok
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def create 
    @article = Article.create({
        title: Faker::Book.title,
        body: Faker::Lorem.sentence
        })

        if(@article.save)
            redirect_to @article
       else
           render 'new'
       end
end

def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message:'Deleted article', data:@article},status: :ok
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update_attributes(article_params)
        render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message:'Updated article', data:@article},status: :ok
    else
        render json: {status: 'ERROR', message:'Article Not Updated',
        data:@article.errors},status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

private

def article_params
    params.permit(:title, :body)      
end
end
```

Currently it gives me this error:
uninitialized constant ArticlesController::Faker

So being the noob that I am, my question is this, how do I require in gem packages (obviously I come from a node background) like I need?

I've tried doing:
require 'faker'

But that just ended in rails not knowing that file to initialize

I am having trouble seeing why my seeds file had no problem recognizing "Faker" without requiring something in but my controller doesn't know what to do with it.

Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Add the require at the top of the controller and restart your server.

Comment: WOW thank you! I didnt realize that it was me not restarting the server. Duh!